# Testing mobile app feature branch via AppCenter before merging into dev

Tags: git, testflight, git-flow, visual-studio-app-center

So far we've been using AppCenter to automatically deploy to TestFlight on every commit to the dev branch. But now, we'd like to share features via TestFlight before they get merged into dev. What's a good way to automatically push new features to TestFlight before they are 100% ready to be merged into dev?

**Background**: So far we only had one developer working at a time and our workflow was like this:

- UI/UX team sends over a draft
- Developer implements it on new feature branch
- Whenever the feature was ready to review, we merged it into dev,
- It got deployed to TestFlight automatically via Microsoft AppCenter on every commit to dev
- Designer could review it via TestFlight
- We'd integrate changes & fixes
- Merge them into dev again

and so on.

But now we're starting to develop multiple features in parallel and we'd like the designers to be able to review the features before they get merged into dev to review smaller steps along the way while keeping the dev branch clean. If it was only developers to review it, I'd say they should just checkout the branch and test it on their simulator or own device. But we want designers to be able to test it via TestFlight but aren't sure how we can automatically deploy feature branches to TestFlight automatically when they should be reviewed?

**Ideas**:

- Setup a "Sandbox" branch and always use `git checkout sandbox && git reset --hard feature-branch && git push --force` to send a feature to the Sandbox TestFlight App to be reviewed by the designers. Downside: Communication is needed to make sure nobody overwrites the Sandbox until the design review is complete.
- Manually push feature to TestFlight without AppCenter (very annoying, takes a lot of time)

Any other best practices or ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to upload the app manually using Transporter or Xcode. Before that, to test application you can send Diawi link to testers. You could easily manage version control using TFS provided by Microsoft. Give it try. And it's not that much tedious task.

And as now you are working parallelly you can use **Beyond Compare** tool for merging codes of different tasks done by different developers.